# OpenShift CrashLoopBackOff error when deploying Angular 7 app on NodeJs

Tags: angular, deployment, openshift

I am trying to deploy an Angular 7 app on NodeJs in OpenShift, the Build was successful but the POD falls into a CrashLoopBackOff mode. Is this due to an invalid entry point to the app? If so, how and where can we specify to copy the DIST folder to the OUTPUT_DIR? Any help on this regard is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Manas

Comment: I suppose it's because of invalid image which might be published unsuccessfully to internal registry during build process. Check build's logs first, then check pod's events and built/pod's images

Comment: what I see in the POD logs is this "sh: ng: command not found" right after the statement > ng serve. It looks like the command is missing. But the same worked during the build phase "ng build".

Comment: There're assemble and run s2i scripts (see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/s2i.html#s2i-scripts). run script executes your application and The assemble script builds the application artifacts. If you overwrite entrypoint, it might be an issue. Check your image CMD by oc get image <IMAGE> and it should be like /usr/libexec/s2i/run